# pagestyle{fancy} will cause second page to have different alignment

Tags: header-footer, vertical-alignment, fancyhdr

In the below image I copied the second and third page above one another. As you can see the alignment is incorrect. After the third page (including the third page) everything works fine. I am using `\renewcommand\maketitle{` and `\pagestyle{fancy}` to make a custom front page and header and footer. But I have no idea what causes this behavior.

[image: align fail]

## Update 1

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[usenames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

%to be able to use your file as a template 
\newcommand{\TitleOfReport}{Long Header bla bla bla some other words\\
 bla bla bla some other words }
\newcommand{\DateOfReport}{2014}
\newcommand{\AuthorOfReport}{ONE}

%changing the layout
\geometry{hmargin=2.5cm, vmargin=2.5cm } 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{ \textcolor{Gray}{\small\TitleOfReport}}
\fancyfoot[C]{ \textcolor{Gray}{\small\AuthorOfReport ~~ \vline ~~ Another phrase goes here ~~ \vline ~~ \DateOfReport}}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[L,R]{}

%make custom frontpage
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitle{
  \begin{titlepage}
  \begin{center}

  \end{center}\par
  \end{titlepage}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{\TitleOfReport}
\date{\DateOfReport}
\author{\AuthorOfReport}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\maketitle   

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\newpage

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

## Update 2

As *lockstep* pointed out simply put the `\headheight` somewhere in the preamble in this case the following will do the job:

```
\headheight27.0pt
```

or

```
\setlength{\headheight}{27.0pt}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Alright, but this will last some minutes.

Comment: It may be related to the fact that the initial page uses `\pagestyle{plain}`.

Comment: Look in the log file and you'll see a warning by `fancyhdr` that tells you how to set `\headheight`.

Comment: I left everything in the source that I think may contribute to the issue. Therefore I left all package imports.

Comment: @lockstep you are right with your assumption.  I was so busy to copy the source together from all my files that I haven’t read the comments coming up.